# Why ggplot says lengths of x,y are different?

Tags: r, shiny

[image]

`length(colnames(datasetInput())) = 105` and `length(datasetInput()[2,]) = 105`
I wonder why ggplot says length of `x`, `y` are different

I check dataframe called datasetInput. Maybe Problem can be name of column is unknown. But `length(colnames(datasetInput())=105` and `colnames` are exist as you see.

```
output$Plot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(datasetInput(), aes( x = colnames((datasetInput())),  
                            y = (datasetInput())[2,] )) + geom_line()
```

> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): x, y

Comment: `x` and `y` should be names of columns in the data frame `datasetInput()`. For example, `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_line()`. It looks like you're trying to plot the column names on the x-axis and row 2 of the data frame on the y-axis. This isn't how ggplot works. Can you say more about what you're trying to do? The error says your data has five rows, and that's the length ggplot expects the x and y columns to be. For example, try `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=colnames(mtcars), mtcars[2, , drop=TRUE])) + geom_line()`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I change code to ggplot(, aes( x = colnames((datasetInput())), y = (datasetInput())[2,] )) + geom_line().

Comment: Another error: default method not implemented for type 'list'. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Now it looks like you're trying to plot column names and a row of data without using ggplot's data argument. Once again, this isn't how ggplot is set up to work. [This chapter](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) from the book *R for Data Science* might be helpful in learning how to use ggplot2.